# In 2017, what is the best way to migrate an entity framework application away from using EDMX while preserving the relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, edmx

I've seen a number of old question's asking the same ([Tool to convert Entity Framework EDMX to Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333834/tool-to-convert-entity-framework-edmx-to-code-first)) but most back in 2009-2014 ([EF "Model First": Create entity in edmx and db-table from class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728145/ef-model-first-create-entity-in-edmx-and-db-table-from-class) / [How to generate Entity Framework 6.x POCO classes with mappings from an EDMX file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405734/how-to-generate-entity-framework-6-x-poco-classes-with-mappings-from-an-edmx-fil)) so would like to ask if the situation is any better in 2017!

We have an EDMX, which we've already set to use the DbContext generator- this gives cleaner POCO's and a leaner context derived from DbContext and not the now ancient ObjectContext but would love to totally ditch the (completely unmergeable) edmx, however keeping the many *many* relationships we have between the 60-odd entities we have.  Simply removing the tt templates currently in place, loses all that entity relationship data.

Is there now a tool or methodology which could help achieve this?  I can't believe that Microsoft themselves haven't released a tool (the powertools aside as I believe they don't generate the relationships)

Comment: Do the relations only exist in your EDMX? Doesn't your database have relations? Anyway directly asking for tools is off-topic, so I'd edit that out if I were you.

Comment: It's a mix- newer entities have relationships, there are some older one's which don't. It's enormous. This is my dilemma- edit it to say what? A tool or technique to perform a specific coding task is exactly what I'm after. Is there a better forum I should be asking this in?

Comment: @Shawson: There is a good mix of people in the C# Chatroom if you want a RL chat:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c